# Buttons that change color of a Range and a DblClick to revert the changes

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am looking to edit my current code as it is very long winded but if need be I can stick with it. My current code is simply repeated on each button as it runs through ActiveX buttons (these buttons must stay). Undo action is preferred but changing the colour back using RGB is a viable option.

My coding is as follows:

```
Private Sub btn3_Click()
     Sheet1.Range("A84:J84").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
End Sub
```

This changes the cell range to a grey colour succesfully, I now need a double click to undo the action or something that will change the colours back to the original colour; I made two attempts.

**Using undo function.**

```
Private Sub btn3_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Application.Undo
       Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Then I tried a different method and went to change the colour.**

```
Private Sub btn3_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim color_index As Long
        color_index = 10
        Sheet1.Range("A84:J84").Interior.Color(color_index) = RGB(153, 153, 255)
End Sub
```

**End result was unsuccessful in both attempts.**

Neither of these worked and would like a 'work around' or to fix my errors, any ideas accepted but I must keep buttons I cannot use 'Cell Selection'.

**EDIT**
If possible there my be an array method useable, I am not good with using ActiveX controls so any advice will most likely be very useful.

My workbook explaining what btn3 represents.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/35p2f.png

Comment: What are you attempting to do with `color_index` in the second attempt? Either you're hard-assigning the `RGB` value, or you're assigning an index. Which do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry that is because you are seeing my struggling attempts to fix the issue being merged into one, I'll edit it now. Also I would like to hard assign RGB value I believe that will work; if an undo button is difficult but can be done I would very much like to do that. :)

Comment: Nevermind, I have just taken a look and realised how stupid I was being problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do `Application.Undo` to undo the results of a macro-performed operation. You either need to create a cache/copy of the data and revert to that, or you need to formulate a way to "undo" in a custom function.

In any case, the error in your second method, this line:

```
Sheet1.Range("A84:J84").Interior.Color(color_index) = RGB(153, 153, 255)
```

Could eeither be changed to:

```
Sheet1.Range("A84:J84").Interior.ColorIndex = color_index
```

Or:

```
Sheet1.Range("A84:J84").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 153, 153)
```

Alternatively, you can do a custom undo function, something like this:

```
'## Module level variable
Dim previousColor As Long

Sub btn3_Click()
    '## stores the current ColorIndex property of the range
    '   (assumes all cells have the same color)
    previousColor = Sheet1.Range("A84:J84").Interior.ColorIndex

    '## Applies the new color:
    Sheet1.Range("A84:J84").Interior.ColorIndex = 16

End Sub

Sub btn3_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Sheet1.Range("A84:J84").Interior.ColorIndex = previousColor
End Sub
```

Further, you inquire:

> as I updated is there a way to do this on a mass scale as I have 60+ 'buttons'...

Yes. Ensure firstly that all of the buttons call the same procedures.  Then, modify the procedures for each button like below. **NOTE** I can't get the double-click to work without also invoking the single-click event, first, which has the undesired effect of not being able to "store" the previous color for the range. You may be able to add some conditional logic, for the time being I've hard-coded so the "undo" function will revert to *no color at all*:

```
Dim previousColor As Long '

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print "click"
    Call changeColor(CommandButton1)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "dbl click"
    Call undoChangeColor(CommandButton1)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Debug.Print "click"
    Call changeColor(CommandButton2)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "dbl click"
    Call undoChangeColor(CommandButton2)
End Sub

Private Sub changeColor(btn As MSForms.CommandButton)
    'Assumes all cells are same color initially
    previousColor = -4142 '(none) 'Sheet1.Range("A84:J84").Interior.ColorIndex

    'Get the row corresponding with each button:
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A" & btn.TopLeftCell.Row).Resize(1, 11)

    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 16   'Modify as needed
                                                            'you could assign the RGB() here

End Sub


Private Sub undoChangeColor(btn As MSForms.CommandButton)

    'Get the row corresponding with each button:
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A" & btn.TopLeftCell.Row).Resize(1, 11)

    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = previousColor
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you David I changed it to "Sheet1.Range("A84:J84").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 153, 255)"

Comment: Before finishing up here can I ask opinion on how you may change how I have done this all together...

Comment: See the addition to my answer, revised :)

Comment: Thank you David, this has solved my issues, as I updated is there a way to do this on a mass scale as I have 60+ 'buttons'...and I do not believe you can collapse coding on vba.

Comment: I can't quite get this to work because the `dbl_Click` procedure is also triggering the `_Click` procedure.

Comment: See revision for handling multiple buttons.  Basically, you want to have each button's event procedures call on the function that changes colors. You can pass the button object to those functions, and use the `.TopLeftCell` to determine which row needs to be colored/uncolored.

Comment: Your original method worked for me, apparently this is acceptable.